# Loading namespaced functions using composer/PSR

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, namespace-organisation

I know how to load my classes properly using composer, and how to name and organize folder/files/class for PSR-4

However, I'm having a use case I've never faced before, and can't seem to find a proper answer here or anywhere about the (or at least one of the) right way to do it

I have namespaced function, without any classes, in my composer library and I would like to make them accessible

```
namespace Foo\Bar;

function baz() {};
```

How am I supposed to organize this on disk, and how do I configure/load it in composer ? In a way that doesn't scream "I hacked at it until something kind of did what I wanted for some reason"

EDIT:

I know I could potentially use static function in a class and that's probably where I will go if I can't find any better, but that's really like sidestepping the issue with. They're functions, not static function of a class.

About the possible duplicate given in comment: I know I can force-require the file to make the function available, the question is how do I do it in a way that the file isn't always required, but only where the user want to use it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That other question is ultimately about requiring files all the time, I'm looking for something that wouldn't force it to be required on all pages where it's never going to be used but only where needed/asked.

Comment: If you want to lazy load functions, you need to wrap them in a class. Only classes get's loaded like that. You can't do it with functions.

Comment: There's no language support for function autoloading. Much less in PSR-x. For namespaced functions any workaround would be [more elaborate even](http://fossil.include-once.org/canonic_autoloader/wiki/rfc:function_autoloading)